# Unhandled access violation exception

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Добрый день.
Есть следующий код на c++(среда - Visual Studio 2013):

```
try
{
    auto lib = LoadLibraryA(libPath.c_str());
    auto func = reinterpret_cast<FuncType>(GetProcAddress(lib, funcName.c_str()));
    func();
}       
catch (...)
{
    //обработка
}
```

Доступа к исходникам загружаемой длл нету. Эта длл в свою очередь обращается к msxml6.dll в которой в ходе исполнения функции func бросается Access Violation. Несмотря на то, что в настройках компилятора выставлен флаг /EHa - в обработчик по многоточию мы не попадаем.

Пробовал делать вот так:

```
try
{
    int* p = nullptr;
    *p = 5;
}       
catch (...)
{
    //обработка
}
```

Тут в обработчик попадаем. Т.е. некоторые Access Violation ловятся.

Вопрос: есть ли вариант поймать исключение из первого отрывка кода? __try/__except пробовал с нулевым результатом, как и _set_se_translator.

Comment: Обычно сначала проверяют `lib` на `null`, а потом  `func`

Comment: И lib и func не null. Ловить надо)

Comment: В Ассеss Violation есть адрес сбоя. Если он не нулевой - 1. открываете дебагер, 2. грузите библиотеки  3. Открываете ассемблерный дебагер - и ставите точку останова. 4. Мучаете дебагом. это часный случай. По другому не отловить.

Comment: Вариант 2. Если вам нужно просто сообщить что возникла ошибка - создаёте ему отдельный Thread, ждете Wait-ом, а потом смотрите статус Thread-а.

Comment: Это все и так крутится в отдельном потоке, правда в std'шном. Суть в том, что от этого исключения падает программа, что недопустимо. Поэтому его нужно как-то перехватить. Сейчас попробовал WinAPI'шный поток вместо std'шного с тем же результатом.

Comment: Ловить access violation нельзя. У вас критический баг, вы должны не замазать его, а исправить. Если в коде произошёл access violation, внутреннее состояние вашей программы безнадёжно испорчено. Не пытайтесь «поднять» код, иначе потом прибежите сюда же с «невозможными» ошибками.